# Problem when creating a menu by iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue and vuetify. I need to create a submenu and for that I am using v-menu. Its construction is by iteration, where I need each sub menu to assign it a method. But it turns out that the way I'm doing it generates an error
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: 'TypeError: handler.apply is not a function'
. What am I doing wrong?
https://codepen.io/maschfederico/pen/vMWBPV?editors=1011

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <v-menu>
        <template #activator="{ on: menu }">
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template #activator="{ on: tooltip }">
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                dark
                v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }"
              >Dropdown w/ Tooltip</v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Im A ToolTip</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click="item.f"
          >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me1',f:'login'},
      { title: 'Click Me2',f:'login' },
      { title: 'Click Me3',f:'login' },
      { title: 'Click Me4' ,f:'login' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    login(){console.log('login')}
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the method name to another one and handle it inside the last one like :

```
     <v-list-tile
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        @click="handle(item.f)"
      >
```

inside the methods :

```
  methods: {
    handle(f){
      this[f]();
    },
    login(){console.log('login')}
  }
```

check [`this codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMEzMz?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the method's name - a string - instead of a function. The click event listener generated by vue is trying to call a function using [apply](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp), this is why you are getting that error.

One solution would be to pass directly the function when the Vue instance is [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) (before that, the method might not be available, so passing it directly to the data `{ title: 'Click Me1', f: this.login }` would not work).

For example, you could keep having method names in the data, and replace them with the actual methods at create:

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me1', f: 'login' }
    ]
  }),
  created () {
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      item.f = this[item.f]
    })
  },
  methods: {
    login (){
      console.log('login')
    }
  }
})
```